# Query which returns needed result from table with duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

We have 2 tables:

Customers:

```
select name, i_customer from Customers limit 5;

| Western Refinishers (Pty) Ltd             |       2265 |
| Westonaria Motor Investments (Pty) Ltd    |       1949 |
| Wild Break 1479 cc                        |       1225 |
| Workshop On Wheels (Pty) Ltd              |       2582 |
| Wynberg Panelbeaters And Spray Painters   |       2471 |
```

Custom_Field_Values:

```
select i_customer, i_custom_field, value
from Custom_Field_Values
where i_custom_field in (14,15,16,17,18) limit 5;

+------------+----------------+-------+
| i_customer | i_custom_field | value |
+------------+----------------+-------+
|         64 |             14 | 101   |
|        321 |             14 | 101   |
|        321 |             16 | 2233  |
|       1519 |             14 | 102   |
|       1529 |             14 | 102   |
+------------+----------------+-------+
```

The same customer can have multiple records in Custom_Field_Values table. For example with i_custom_field 14 and 16.

I need to retrieve a report which returns all Customer unique names and Custom_Field_Values.values only for records with i_custom_field with numbers 16,17,18.

If Customer does not have a record with i_custom_field in (16,17,18) just replace its value with empty string.

Comment: How about using `LEFT JOIN` for each of the desired custom fields?

Comment: how about if a customer has multiple line in Custom_Field_Values with i_custom_field in (16,17,18) ?

Comment: What about the other matching?? There should be loss of other data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT c.name, cfv.value 
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN Customer_Field_Values cfv
ON c.i_customer = cfv.i_customer
AND cfv.i_custom_field > 15
AND cfv.i_custom_field < 19;
```

Answer (score 0):

If multiple rows with i_custom_field in (16,17,18) is found for the same customer, the value is summed up as the output value.

Here is the solution.

```
SELECT 
    c.name, COALESCE( SUM(v.value), '') value
FROM 
    Customers c LEFT JOIN Custom_Field_Values v USING(i_customer)
WHERE 
    v.i_custom_field IN (16, 17, 18)
GROUP BY 
    c.name
```